# what does const and props refer to in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
export default class customer  {

}

render(){
    const{
        handleSubmit,
        pristine,
        submitting
    } = this.props;
    return{
        <div>
        </div>
    }  
}
```

my react-redux code has something like this. can any one tell me why we are using `const` and `this.props` in the code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> can any one tell me why we are using "const"

[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is another way to declare a variable. These variables disallow reassignment. `const` is generally a safer way to declare variables, depending on the developer's intent.

> can any one tell me why we are using this.props in the code

That's an assignment/deconstructing shorthand. The syntax is something like this:

```
var {
  property
} = object;
```

What you're doing is creating local variables from the properties of the object. That code is identical to:

```
var property = object.property;
```

So in your code, you can think of

```
const {
    handleSubmit,
    pristine,
    submitting
} = this.props;
```

as simply

```
const handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit;
const pristine = this.props.pristine;
const submitting = this.props.submitting;
```

Comment: "const is another way to declare a variable" – I would use the term "value", instead of "variable".

Comment: Also using `var` is discouraged (e.g. by Eslint), so I suggest to use `let` in your examples.

Comment: @Pavlo Since OP was unaware of `const`, I figured using `let` in an example would lead to more confusion. Also this is a _highly_ debated topic — I personally think `let` conveys that the variable is only going to be used within a particular block scope, while `var` tells me that that variable lives within the entire function scope.

Comment: Values and variables are two different things. `5` is a value. `var a = 5` is a variable (with the value `5`). Imo it's better to be precise than to use "simpler" words.

Comment: @ArneHugo Yeah after some more thinking and deliberation, I think describing `const` as a variable is more accurate here. A variable is a means of storing data — which is exactly what `const` is. If anything, `const` describes the _variable_ and not so much its _value_ — it says that the variable itself cannot be reassigned, regardless of the value @Pavlo